# Yarn error "no such option" with --dev flag

Tags: yarnpkg

`ignite-ir-boilerplate` was not able to be installed. Is it a valid NPM module?

```
Command failed: yarn add ignite-ir-boilerplate --dev
Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: --dev
```

Comment: What's your yarn version?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> You probably installed yarn using this:
>   `$ apt install cmdtest`

Use this instead:
`$ npm install --global yarn`

Comment: What is this? yarn != yarn?

Comment: It works for me, thank you! After installing, the error message will persist. You should log out and log in into ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

Add sudo before, works for me,

```
sudo yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```