# Yarn add --dev returning --> yarn: error: no such option: --dev

Tags: yarnpkg

I have looked at this post: 
[Yarn error "no such option" with --dev flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430645/yarn-error-no-such-option-with-dev-flag) but it did not work for me. I did the `npm install --global yarn` and it did not work.

```
yarn version: 0.27
node version: 9.6.1
npm version: 5.6.0
linux-ubuntu: 17.10
```

commad being run:

```
yarn add --dev nodemon babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-preset-stage-3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem while running the command:

```
yarn add --dev eslint prettier eslint-config-airbnb@^15.0.1 eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.1.1

yarn: error: no such option: --dev
```

adding *sudo* to the command helped me!

sudo npm install --global yarn

Answer (score 5):

from [@Wangai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219526/wangai) you probably installed `$ apt install yarn`
Instead use `$ sudo npm install --global yarn`, then run your command.

Reference: [Yarn error "no such option" with --dev flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430645/yarn-error-no-such-option-with-dev-flag)