# yarn init -y Usage: yarn [options] yarn: error: no such option: -y

Tags: yarnpkg

The problem I met when I use

`yarn init -y`

the problem occurred:

```
yarn init -y
Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: -y
```

what's the reason behind it?

Comment: You should view this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430645/yarn-error-no-such-option-with-dev-flag?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: it was 2 years ago, but anyway thankyou so much